# How to select svg child element of a div using d3 select

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, d3.js, svg

I have assigned a ref to access my functional component **div**. The ref works fine.

Now, I want to access the SVG using this ref and d3 select. However, I am facing issues to do that.

Below is the structure of DOM that I am trying to access:

```
<div style="height: 500px;">
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"> <--- Third party DOM starts here
    <div style="position: relative;">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" width="1904" height="500">
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div> <---- Third Party DOM ends here
</div>
```

Below is the React component that I have created.

```
const MyFunctionComponent = ({ data }) => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  let parentDiv;

  useEffect(() => {
    parentDiv = d3.select(ref.current).select("div");
    console.log(parentDiv);
  });

  return (
    <div style="height: 500px;" ref={ref}>
        <ThirdPartyLibraryComponent/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

console.log gives the attached result:

[image]

When I change the d3 selection to:
`parentDiv = d3.select(ref.current).select("div").select("div");`

I get the below result:

[image]

How can I correctly access the SVG?

Here is the codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-d3-select-98rhq)

Comment: I am not following exactly what you're trying to do here, but you don't need to select each element on the way. D3 selections work like CSS. Simply writing `d3.select(ref.current).select("svg")` might work.

Comment: I tried that but it does not work. I have updated the question with my codesandbox link, in case it helps.

Answer (score 0):

SVG was not yet attached to the DOM by the third party library. Hence, I was not able to find the SVG element.

Below is a temporary solution:

```
  const checkSVGExists = () => {
    if (ref.current) {
      let parentDiv = d3.select(ref.current);
      if (parentDiv.node().querySelector("svg") !== null) {
        let svg = parentDiv.select("svg");
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      checkSVGExists();
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  });
```